# jQuery autocomplete strange error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I am using [this plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) and in some pages I get an

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'toLowerCase' error.**

The error reffers to jQuery.min.js, but it fails when I am trying to type something in field while the suggest list already open. And there is no any server request in that case.

Anyone? Thank you

UPD: **SOLVED**

Comment: You should be using the autocomplete plugin that is a integral part of jquery-ui, since its derived from the one in your link.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I can see the notification at developer's page:)

Comment: Hi @JanDragsbaek you should stick your comment as an answer so it can be marked as the solution - earn ye some mega points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, you should be using the more recent version included in the jQuery-ui.